# Query for specific timestamp format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to query the database for specific time in oracle. The specific timestamp format is `12-JUL-19 10.05.52.188000000 AM`

I want to write a query to get all the records during specific time without mentioning the milliseconds but I want AM/PM to be mentioned at the end of time.

I am able to write a normal SQL Query but without AM/PM.

Can someone help?

Comment: Try `where urtstampcol = to_timestamp('12-JUL-19 10.05.52.188000000 AM','DD.MON.YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM') ` .   [**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd2d91268c39fdf58a7667c9267ad847)

Comment: Thanks @KaushikNayak, How do I use the WHERE clause with above query?

Comment: You have to replace your where clause with mine. That's all

Comment: `timestamp` columns do **not** have "a format" - you can format it when you _display_ the value.

Comment: Please provided the query you like to execute, then we can support you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 24 hours format.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('18/07/2019 09:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: if your column is a date format you can use:

`select * from TABLE where COLUMNNM=TO_TIMESTAMP('18/07/2019 09:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');`



If your column is a varchar, then u can format it first. example:

`select * from TABLE where TO_TIMESTAMP(COLUMNNM, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')=TO_TIMESTAMP('18/07/2019 09:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');`